# How to create unique URL with post title from my database?

Tags: php

I want to create a link from a post title in my site. When anyone posts in my site they post some fields; one is a title. I can create the link in title but i want to show in address bar link only `mysite.com/the post of title`, like this. I do not want to display the details page.

Now my post URL displays like this `mysite.com/page name then id then post title`. How do i remove page name, id ?

This is my code 
         **[a] href="view-items-details.php?ID=<  php echo $row['sl'];?>&show=">View Details[ a ][1]**

This will display in address bar like

```
     **mysite/view-item-details?ID=somthing&show=somthing**
```

I want to show in address bar link only

```
     **mysite/post title**
```

What should i do?

Comment: It is impossible to tell what you are asking from this question. Why are you adding the name and id to the URL if you don't want them? Please post some code; otherwise, no one can help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you to read about the term clean urls, then edit your .htaccess file very carefully. Its not that difficult to achieve but demands some basic knowledge about it.

**Try this.**

> http://www.desiquintans.com/articles.php?page=cleanurls